# PHP Interface class in function arguments

Tags: php, function, class, interface, listener

I want use PHP interface like Java interface.
How i do this work in PHP?

Android (Java):

```java
btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //---------------------------------
    }
});
```

I want in PHP:

```php
$installer->setOnInstallerListener(new IInstaller(){
    function onError()
    {
        echo 'OK';
    }
});
```

IInstaller is a Interface:

```php
interface IInstaller
{
    public function onError();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems PHP7 has support for this. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php

```
new class(10) extends SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    private $num;

    public function __construct($num)
    {
        $this->num = $num;
    }

    use SomeTrait;
}
```

With PHP5 the best you can do is mimick the behavior using closures: http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/mimicking-anonymous-classes-in-php-using-closures

Comment: What mean 10 in "new class(10)"?

Comment: 10 is the constructor value. So if you have empty constructor you can leave that out